# Different Entry point for same source code in the ELF file

Tags: gcc, elf

I am trying to achieve reproducibility of builds, and in order to do that I am compiling same code with same compiler on other machine(one is on my Ubuntu machine) and the other is another ubuntu machine with same configuration.
The ELF file for both are different, specifically the entry point are different.

Can someone explain why? different compiler version generating different output is acceptable but  exactly same compiler for exact same code generating different ELF is something I don't understand.

I am using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9) 5.4.0 20160609 on both the machine.